# Disable event firing itself from its code

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

`SelectedIndexChange` event is causing my trouble here as I change `index` in this event and I would like to avoid it.

I still need to call the event when I change index manually but **not in code**. Because as you may notice when I change index inside the event it fires itself again.

Comment: You could either temporarily unsubscribe the event, or set a flag somewhere that says you are currently in an operation and exit the event if the flag is true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a boolean to specify that you are inside event.

```
private bool _isRunning = false;
private void SelectedIndexChange(...)
{
    if(_isRunning) return;
    _isRunning = true;

    // do your things

    _isRunning = false;
}
```

Edit. As noted by Scott Chamberlain if there is potential of happening error inside event then use `finally` statement to always reset flag.

```
private bool _isRunning = false;
private void SelectedIndexChange(...)
{
    if(_isRunning) return;
    _isRunning = true;
    try
    {
        // do your things
    }
    finally
    { 
        _isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to wrap that in a `try/finally` so in the event of a error `_isRunning` is reset.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks for the useful information.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by [Ron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4798077/ron-beyer) in comments you can remove the handler from event and do your job and then assign handler to event again:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Remove handler
    this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;

    //Change index here

    //Assign handler again
    this.comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
}
```

Also the other way that Ron has suggested is implemented by [M.Kazem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4767498/m-kazem-akhgary) and you can use that option as well.

Comment: You may want to wrap that in a `try/finally` so in the event of a error the event is re-subscribed.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain It's very very good idea to put it in `try/finally` to guarantee re-subscribing to event.